# Limit of the complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, polynomials

I don't understand the limit of the complex polynomial $p(z)=a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_nz^n$.
\begin{align}
\lim_{\lvert z \rvert \rightarrow\infty}\Bigg \lvert \frac{p(z)}{z^n} \Bigg \rvert&= \lim_{\lvert z \rvert \rightarrow\infty}\Bigg \lvert \frac{a_0}{z^n}+\frac{a_1}{z^{n-1}}+\cdots +\frac{a_{n-1}}{z} + a_n\Bigg \rvert\\
&=\lvert a_n\rvert
\end{align}
**Questions:**

I get that $\lim_{\lvert z \rvert \rightarrow\infty} \Big\lvert \frac{a_{n-1}}{z}\Big \rvert=``\Big\lvert \frac{a_{n-1}}{\infty}\Big \rvert``=0$.

However:

1. Why is $\lim_{\lvert z \rvert \rightarrow\infty} \Big\lvert \frac{a_0}{z^n}\Big \rvert=0$? The limit is for $z$ and not for $z^n$, so isn't this term just a constant?
2. Why is the second term zero? Isn't $\lim_{\lvert z \rvert \rightarrow\infty} \Big\lvert \frac{a_1}{z^{n-1}}\Big \rvert=\lim_{\lvert z \rvert \rightarrow\infty} \Bigg\lvert \frac{a_1}{\frac{z^n}{z}}\Bigg \rvert=\lim_{\lvert z \rvert \rightarrow\infty} \Big\lvert \frac{za_1}{z^n}\Big \rvert=\infty$?

I thought incorrectly the limit would be
\begin{align}
\lim_{\lvert z \rvert \rightarrow\infty}\Bigg \lvert \frac{p(z)}{z^n} \Bigg \rvert&= \lim_{\lvert z \rvert \rightarrow\infty}\Bigg \lvert \frac{a_0}{z^n}+\infty+\cdots +0 + a_n\Bigg \rvert\\
&=\lvert \infty\rvert=\infty
\end{align}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{|z|\to\infty}\left|\frac{a}{z^k}\right|=\lim_{|z|\to\infty}\frac{|a|}{|z|^k}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{|a|}{x^k}=\frac{|a|}{\infty}=0$$
it holds for every $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and every $k>0$, in particulary $k=1,\dots,n$ and $a=a_{n-k}$